# Elementary set notation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

Trivially, $\mathbb{N}$ may be represented as the collection of subsets $\rm{O}_{1},\rm{O}_{2},\rm{O}_{3}\dots\rm{O}_{n}$, where $\rm{O}_{1}$ is the set of all odds, $\rm{O}_{2}=2 \rm{O}_{1}$, $\rm{O}_{3}=2 \rm{O}_{2}, \dots \rm{O}_{n}=2 \rm{O}_{n-1}$. What is the best way to write this in terms of set notation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb N=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N\cup\{0\}}2^n O_1$.

Comment: Much simpler (and far more elegant)! many thanks! :)

Comment: Not exactly. If $0\notin\mathbb N$ then the right side contains only even numbers. If $0\in\mathbb N$, then $0$ belongs to the left side of the equation but not to the right side.

Comment: So what would be the best way of saying this in terms of set notation? (Please excuse my ignorance in this matter.)

Comment: Maybe replace Yiorgos's $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb N\cup\{\emptyset}\}$ or $\bigcup_{n=0}^\infty\ $?

Comment: Great - thanks :)